# how to get username via checked checkbox with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i[image]

**HTML**

```
  <div id="notApprovedUsers">

                            </div><button onclick="approveUsers()">Approve</button>
                            </div>
```

i like to get checked users in parameter `userList` to work with.

here is javascript there me generating list with users and checkboxes.
i like to approve just the checked one's of course!

**JavaScript**

```
function getNotAssignedUsers() {

server.getUsersByGroup("1eb33e30-c355-467f-af3c-e7d0b4a1fgt5").then(function (userDetails) {
    debugger;

    for (var i = 0; i < userDetails.length; i++)
    {
        var vorname = userDetails[i].firstName;
        var nachname = userDetails[i].lastName;

        var newCheckBox = document.createElement('input');
        newCheckBox.type = 'checkbox';
        newCheckBox.id = "0"+i;
        document.getElementById("notApprovedUsers").appendChild(newCheckBox);


        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.id = i;
        newElement.className = "notApprovedUsers";
        newElement.innerHTML = vorname + " " + nachname;
        document.getElementById("notApprovedUsers").appendChild(newElement);
    }                                         
});
```

}

**HERE** in userList I need to read just a checked users..

```
function approveUsers(userList)
{
    var user1 = document.getElementById("00").checked;
    var user2 = document.getElementById("01").checked;
    var user3 = document.getElementById("02").checked;

    alert(user1 || user2 || user3);
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this jquery, why not `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')`?

Comment: how to solve my problem with jquery??? get all usernames?

Comment: Whats the markup for your checkboxes? Otherwise we can only assume the html structure

Comment: its generated with javascript as showed above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this then. There may be errors as I havent tested

```
var names = [];

$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(index, value){

    var name = $(value).next("div").html();
    names.push(name);
});
```

Then do something with the names array

Edit - See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vpg3r/3/

Comment: its nice. do you know maybe where the error is? "name" is always as undefined by me

Comment: probably because I got the index and value parameters the wrong way round sorry (its been a long day). Check the jsfiddle to see it in action

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you here is to use **jQuery**. You can use something like:

```
$('#notApprovedUsers input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

to get all the elements that are checked, and work with them.
I've created a JSFiddle for you to demonstrate how to implement the behavior that I'm describing. [You can see it in this link](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/UB75C/1/).